# How to detect "class" from clicked "div", having several items with same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scenario somewhat like this,

```
<div>
   <div class="check">
     <p class="user-name">
       <a href=url>name</a>
     </p>
     <i class="user-icon"></i>
     <div class="activity">
       <p class="status">Status</p>
       <p class="stream">Stream</p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="check">
     <p class="user-name">
       <a href=url>name</a>
     </p>
     <i class="user-icon"></i>
     <div class="activity">
       <p class="status">Status</p>
       <p class="stream">Stream</p>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and, I'm to `.slideToggle()` the `div` with `class`name `activity` of that particular `div` whenever user clicks upon any element inside `div` with `class`name `check`.
I've came up with this one,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".check").click(function(){
           $(".activity").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

And, as it's seen, its should not work, as it acts upon all the `div`s with `class`name `activity`.

And I can't change the `class`names into `id`s, as these are auto populated through another `function`, and easier for styling through `css` and maintenance.

I want it to act upon only that `div` on which user will `click`.

How can I do so?

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is 'user-activity' class in your html ?

Comment: Oh sorry. The "user-activity" will be "activity" only. While editing for stackoverflow, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select it properly, and make sure you use `.activity` instead of `.user-activity` (which doesn't exist):

```
$(".activity", this).slideToggle();
```

or

```
$(this).find(".activity").slideToggle();
```

---

See it in action here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".check").click(function(){
           $(".activity", this).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.check .activity {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <div class="check">
     <p class="user-name">
       <a>name</a>
     </p>
     <i class="user-icon"></i>
     <div class="activity">
       <p class="status">Status</p>
       <p class="stream">Stream</p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="check">
     <p class="user-name">
       <a>name</a>
     </p>
     <i class="user-icon"></i>
     <div class="activity">
       <p class="status">Status</p>
       <p class="stream">Stream</p>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And while editing for stackoverflow, I didn't notice "user-activity", thanks for pointing that out (question edited).

Comment: No problem, I thought it was a typo, but still wanted to include it so you can see all the changes I've made for the live example.

Comment: Yes it was. Thanks for the example :)

Answer (score 1):

The event handler will be called in the context of the element upon which it was fired, so just use `this` to access it.

You can combine that with jQuery's `find` method to look for the associated descendant element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find selector to find activity element in currently clicked div:

```
$(".check").click(function(){
   $(this).find('.activity').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use this  **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w7h5xhxw/1/)**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".check").click(function(){
           $(this).children('.activity').slideToggle();
           //OR you may also use   $(this).find('.activity').slideToggle();
    });
});
```